# Не могу вывести информацию на сайт через PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

В php особо не шарю и mysql тоже не очень.
Помогите пожалуйста
Код:

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=categories_kalkulyator', "root", "");

$info = [];

if ($query = $db→query(statement:"SELECT * FROM 1")) {
$info = $query→fetchAll(fetch_style:pDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} else {
print_r($db→errorInfo());
}

?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка которую выдаёт на сайте:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')' in C:\OSPanel\domains\local123\kalkulyator.php on line 7

серв создал с openserver'a, бд тоже
Всё делал по этому видео:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3m8quiQCFU&t=914s

Comment: `statement:` и `fetch_style:` уберите

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с *PHP8* можно в фунции и методы передавать [именованные аргументы](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php#functions.named-arguments)

Получается ошибку можно исправить:

- Либо поставить у себя версию >= *PHP8.0*
- Либо убрать у себя именованные аргументы

Comment: поставил PHP8.1, НЕ ПОМОГЛО

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1'' at line 1 in C:\OSPanel\domains\local123\kalkulyator.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\OSPanel\domains\local123\kalkulyator.php(7): PDO->query() #1 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\local123\kalkulyator.php on line 7

Comment: Не правда. **Помогло**! Потому что это уже другая ошибка, связанная совсем с другим....и вам вполне себе пишут что не так